# Solve the equation

Tags: complex-numbers

Solve the equation $$2{z^2} + 2z + 2iz - 5i = 0
$$

I used the quadratic formula and I have simplified it down to $$\frac{{ - (1 + i) \pm \sqrt {11i} }}{2}$$
Is this correct? Could it be simplified even more?

Comment: Well, it's not in $x+iy$ form...

Comment: What is $z$? Is $z$ purely real?

Comment: @PrasunBiswas This would have no solution if that were the case -- so I'm going to say that $z$ is almost certainly complex valued.

Answer (score 1):

There was some error in your calculation, we have

$$\begin{align}
z&=\frac{-(2+2i)\pm\sqrt{(2+2i)^2-4(2)(-5i)}}{2(2)}
\\&=\frac{-(2+2i)\pm\sqrt{8i+40i}}{4}
\\&=\frac{-(2+2i)\pm\sqrt{48i}}{4}
\\&=\frac{-(2+2i)\pm4\sqrt{3i}}{4}
\\&=\frac{-(1+i)\pm2\sqrt{3i}}{2}
\end{align}$$

Okay, and now we are basically in the same situation.

From here, we can rewrite $\sqrt{i}$. Note that $i=e^{\frac{\pi i}{2}}$, so we can write $$\sqrt{i}=\sqrt{e^{\frac{\pi i}{2}}}=i=e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i$$

Hence we have

$$\begin{align}
z&=\frac{-(1+i)\pm2\sqrt{3i}}{2}
\\&=\frac{-(1+i)\pm2\sqrt{3}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i\right)}{2}
\\&=\frac{-(1+i)\pm\sqrt{6}\left(1+i\right)}{2}
\\&=\frac{(-1\pm\sqrt{6})(1+i)}{2}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

if you multiply by $2,$  you have $$4z^2 + 4(1+i)z = 10i \to (2z + 1+i)^2 = 10i+(1+i)^2 =12i=\left(\pm \sqrt6(1+i)\right)^2   $$  therefore $$2z + 1+i = \pm \sqrt6(1+i) \to 2z = (\sqrt 6 - 1)(1+i), -(\sqrt 6 + 1)(1+i) $$

Answer (score 0):

the roots are 
$$=\frac{-(1+i)\pm2\sqrt{3i}}{2}$$
now we will use the fact 
$$i=\frac{1}{2}(1+i)^2$$
$$\sqrt{i}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1+i)$$
and then complete the simlifying